# Bibtex could not find .tex.aux

Tags: bibtex, errors

I'm getting the following error message from bibtex.

```
$ bibtex test.tex
I couldn't open file name `test.tex.aux'
```

What is causing this? [NB. I'm about to write an answer to this question.]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to leave out the ".tex" in the invocation of `bibtex`.  I.e. you need to run `bibtex test` rather than `bibtex test.tex`.

Comment: Probably Meta is exactly the place where this can be debated. It's possibly not a bad idea; can you try expanding the question? I'll remove my comments.

Comment: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3070/asking-answering-questions-which-are-discussed-in-every-guide